# set position of row by own on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a result of SQL like this

```
status || value 
 green     3
 blue      39
 pink      2
 black     300
```

I want to change the row of blue and pink

I want to sort like this from `green, pink, blue, and black` for that row and value also
is that possible to the condition that row to be by own?

so the result will be like this

```
status || value 
 green     3
 pink      2
 blue      39
 black     300
```

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(status, "green", "pink", "blue", "black")` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `field()`

```
SELECT status,value
FROM tablename
ORDER BY FIELD(status, "green", "pink", "blue","black")
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select status,value from table
order by case status when 'green' then 1
              when 'pink' then 2
              when 'blue' then 3
              when 'black' then 4 end
```